# Show that α : R → R n (distance on R and R n being usual and Euclidean respectively) defined by α(x) = (x, 0, . . . , 0) is continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We have been given this question. I am new to topology so I'm having a hard time figuring how to solve this out. Can someone help?

Comment: Start by writing the *definition* of a continuous function in this context. Then try to prove that $\alpha(x)$ is continuous, and let us know if and where you get stuck.

Comment: Ok. Will do that.

Comment: I'm trying to prove that it is continuous but I'm not able to

Comment: Are you trying to show continuity through an epsilon-delta definition, or through the inverse image of open sets definition?

Comment: I am using Epsilon-delta

Comment: Then the answer from Henno should help you out.

Comment: Yes I tried it out but it's not coming

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\| \alpha(x) - \alpha(y) \| \le |x-y|$$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: I did this but I don't know how to solve further

Comment: @Mathgeek take $\delta=\epsilon$ at any point.

Comment: Can we prove this question by inverse image of an open set is open??

Comment: @Mathgeek We could, but it wouldn't be easier.

Comment: So can you write the answer properly once coz I'm not getting anywhere